# Is it a way to fill up collectionView lines from the beginning of the line and leave space in the end?

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewlayout

Instead of this alignment:

x-x-x

x-x-x

I need this one:

xxx--

xxx--

Is it possible with `UICollectionViewController`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, what you need to do is subclass UICollectionViewFlowLayout, so you can adjust the UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes by setting the frame of each item to left-align it.

An example of what you are trying to do can be found on Github:

https://github.com/mokagio/UICollectionViewLeftAlignedLayout

This is assuming that you already provide a custom size for each item in your UICollectionView using sizeForItemAtIndexPath.

HTH